# Is there any way to avoid error 9 on execel vba without the help of Error handlers

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub my code ()
Windows."mysheet.xlsm".activate 
end sub
```

I wanted to extract a daily report from my office website. And the name should change daily on the basis of date (eg "`Detail report 11 28 2014.xls`"). So if I run my code it will end up with an error(`error 9`) so my macro becomes useless. 
Please give me a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the name's structure is always the same and what it changes is just the name (because of the days passing), then you could just:

A. Create the date-string of the Workbook's name today:

```
Dim todayYear As Integer: todayYear = Year(Now())
Dim todayMonth As Integer: todayMonth = Month(Now())
Dim todayDay As Integer: todayDay = Day(Now())
'following to put the "0" before the number in case it is < 10
If todayMonth < 10 Then todayMonth = "0" & todayMonth
If todayDay < 10 Then todayDay = "0" & todayDay
'so you build your string MM DD YYYY
Dim myName As String: myName = todayMonth & " " & todayDay & " " & todayYear
```

B. Define your today Workbook's name:

```
Dim myWorkbookToday As String: myWorkbook = "Detail report " & myName & ".xls"
```

C. Activate your workbook:

```
Windows(myWorkbookToday).Activate
```

From a code-structure point of view, specifically, I would put the points A and B into a Function that returns directly the name I need today:

```
Public Function nameToday() As String
   'code of the points A and B here
    nameToday = myWorkbookToday
End Function

Sub myCode()
    Windows(nameToday).Activate
End Sub
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT OF THE FUNCTION nameToday**

- On 28 November 2014, it returns `nameToday = "Detail report 11 28 2014.xls"`
- On 29 November 2014, it returns `nameToday = "Detail report 11 29 2014.xls"`
- etc.